# Value not passed to controller method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have the following view `Board.cshtml`, where I want to render a partial view `MessagesBoard.cshtml` based on an event of `DropDownListFor`.

**Boards.cshtml**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        debugger
        $("#selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages").change(function (e) {
            alert($(this).val());
            var val = $(this).val();
            $("#updateBulletMessagesView").load("UpdateBoardMessages/", { listBulletinBoardsMessages: val });
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.listBulletinBoardsMessages, Model.listBulletinBoardsMessages.Select(b => new SelectListItem() { Value = b.Department, Text = b.Department }), "All Departments",
           new { @class = "form-control",
                 id = "selected_listBulletinBoardsMessages"
       })
</div>

<div id="updateBulletMessagesView">
    @Html.Partial("MessagesBoard")
</div>
```

The Controller method: UpdateBoardMessages does not have a value for the `val` sent from the jQuery script.

```
public ActionResult UpdateBoardMessages(string val)
        {
            val = val; //NULL??
            ..
            return PartialView("MessagesBoard.cshtml");
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your controller action getting called?

Comment: you are  passing the variable as listBulletinBoardsMessages and not val.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yes it does.

Comment: @Fran is you suggestion: "val" instead of "{listBulletionBoardsMe:val}" ?. If so. It doesn't work neither.

Comment: you've got other issues with this code. see Ehsan's answer.  missing controller in your load url.  note how he's not passing  listBulletinBoardsMessages in the url he's passing val.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to use `Url.Action` to generate the correct url instead of using magic strings and then you can add the query string parameter by string conctenation in javascript something like:

```
$("#updateBulletMessagesView").load('@Url.Action("UpdateBoardMessages","ControllerName")'+'?val='+val;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: there's an error `'&val='+val;` must be `'?val='+val;`

Comment: It doesnt actually break on my controller action.